# How to style inline code in block editor?

Tags: shortcode

I have an issue with the inline-code styling. Within the block editor it has the gray background behind the code as intended, but when I go to preview the post, there is no background color on the inline-code tags (the font is changed though).

The separate code-block, however, does have the normal gray background.

What could I do to fix this or make a custom background/font-color for all inline-code tags?
I've tried plenty of plugins and don't want to use the classic editor (tinyMCE).

Is there a way to add this in CSS or some way that it would apply to all inline code tags on all pages always?

Comment: Inline code just uses the `<code>` element. You should be able to style it with CSS like any other element.

Comment: @JacobPeattie You're right. Honestly I seem to have overcomplicated things. Adding some styling to the CSS file within `code { <colors here> }` did the trick.